# function to get title from result object depending on if title is empty

Tags: javascript

I want to rewrite if else statements with something nicer or refactor the code i have to something neat using javascript.

below is the code,

```
const title = () => {
    if (result) {
        //here checking if the title field is not undefined or null and title field 
        //has no empty string ""
        if (result?.title && !isEmpty(result?.title)) return result.title;
        // checking if title is undefined or null or is empty string ""
        if (!result?.title || isEmpty(result?.title)) return something[status] 
        (name);
    } else {
        return titleByStatus[status];
    };
```

could someone help me with this. thanks.
}
could someone help me rewrite this neat. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't need to use `?` inside the `if(result)` block, because you know that its not null or undefined
2. Your two if statements are opposite, use an else block

   ```
   if (result) {
       if (result.title && result.title != "") {
            return result.title;
       } else {
           return something[status](name)
       }
   } else {
       return titleByStatus[status];
   };
   ```

Comment: `&& result.title != ""` is meaningless.  `var a = ""; if (a) alert('a'); else alert('b');`

Comment: IMHO this is still way more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

## 1. extract helpers

```
//here checking if the title field is ...
```

You felt it was worth explaining the code using English words.
Ok, fair enough, that's a good impulse,
one we wish to encourage.
But rather than writing the comment in-line,
consider breaking out a boolean helper
with an informative name like `hasTitle()`.
If you feel there's still more to say,
then by all means write a comment at the top
of that predicate function.

## 2. simplify expressions

```
        if (result?.title && !isEmpty(result?.title)) return result.title;
```

Cautiously using a `result?` guard is definitely helpful.
But once would suffice: `!isEmpty(result?.title)`.
That first conjunct is redundant here.

And it's all redundant with that `if (result) {` guard up top.

## 3. negation

```
        if (!result?.title || isEmpty(result?.title)) return something[status]
```

[De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)
served you well here on this slightly involved expression.
But if you find yourself using both forms,
positive and negative, consider **naming** the concept
and breaking it out to refer to it more conveniently.

The suggestion above would let us refer to:

- `hasTitle(result)` and also to
- `! hasTitle(result)`

Or assign to a temp var, for similar effect.

Or rely on the flow of control.

## 4. control flow

Given a boolean condition `c` we might write:

```
if (c) { return result; }
if (! c) { do_other_things(); }
```

But look at what the first statement did to the flow of control.
If `c` then we've left already!
By the time we get down the second statement,
we *know* for sure that `c` is false.

Equivalently, rely on `else` behavior:

```
if (c) { do_one(); }
else   { do_two(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb a lot of developers have is avoid nested conditions if you can and exit out early if you can. By switching up the order of your code slightly you can make it easy to read.

- So if you move the else condition up to a check and you can exit out.
- You can make one check if you do not have the title
- and finally you can return the title.

```javascript
const title = () => {
  if(!result) return titleByStatus[status];

  if (isEmpty(result.title || '')) return something[status];

  return result.title;
}
```

If your isEmpty code handles undefined/null then you could just get away with

```javascript
if (isEmpty(result.title)) return something[status];
```

Comment: Personally, I find early returns like this harder to follow then else blocks in most cases.

Comment: @WinstonEwert Most style guides stress early returns. Here is a question on engineering stack with opinions https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/should-i-return-from-a-function-early-or-use-an-if-statement

Comment: @WinstonEwert And your answer still has a useless check for an empty string.... :)

Comment: Yes, I get confused about javascript's bool interpretation rules sometimes.

Comment: Most style guides are wrong then :). Actually, the correct answer is it depends. Do what's readable, don't follow a blind rule about taking either approach. In my view, its simply harder to follow your code then my version. Early returns can help, but they aren't helping here.